# if checkbox is checked remove required

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

The user has to select at least one checkbox, once a checkbox is checked, I want to remove `required` from all the checkbox, then if the user unselect, none of the checkbox is checked, reput `required` on them.
My code is not working. I found lots of similar answers here but none of them works for me, so I ask this question again.

Here is [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nba_jl/k94stpby/11/)

```js
var checkbox_required = $('input[type="checkbox"]');

checkbox_required.prop('required', true);

if (checkbox_required.is(':checked'))
{
 checkbox_required.prop('required', false);
}
else
{
 checkbox_required.prop('required', true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label class="produit_type">
    <input type="checkbox" name="produit_type[]" value="奢侈品与配饰">奢侈品与配饰
  </label>
  <label class="produit_type">
    <input type="checkbox" name="produit_type[]" value="女士时尚">女士时尚
  </label>
  <label class="produit_type">
    <input type="checkbox" name="produit_type[]" value="男士时尚">男士时尚
  </label>
  <label class="produit_type">
    <input type="checkbox" name="produit_type[]" value="美妆与护肤">美妆与护肤
  </label>
  <label class="produit_type">
    <input type="checkbox" name="produit_type[]" value="儿童">儿童
  </label>
  <label class="produit_type">
    <input type="checkbox" name="produit_type[]" value="内衣">内衣
  </label>
  <label class="produit_type">
    <input type="checkbox" name="produit_type[]" value="家居">家居
  </label>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you forgot is to add the `on('click', ...` event handler https://jsfiddle.net/nba_jl/k94stpby/12/

```js
var checkbox_required = $('input[type="checkbox"]');

checkbox_required.prop('required', true);

checkbox_required.on('click', function(){
    if (checkbox_required.is(':checked')) {
        checkbox_required.prop('required', false);
    } else {
        checkbox_required.prop('required', true);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form>
  <label class="produit_type">
    <input type="checkbox" name="produit_type[]" value="奢侈品与配饰">奢侈品与配饰
  </label>
  <label class="produit_type">
    <input type="checkbox" name="produit_type[]" value="女士时尚">女士时尚
  </label>
  <label class="produit_type">
    <input type="checkbox" name="produit_type[]" value="男士时尚">男士时尚
  </label>
  <label class="produit_type">
    <input type="checkbox" name="produit_type[]" value="美妆与护肤">美妆与护肤
  </label>
  <label class="produit_type">
    <input type="checkbox" name="produit_type[]" value="儿童">儿童
  </label>
  <label class="produit_type">
    <input type="checkbox" name="produit_type[]" value="内衣">内衣
  </label>
  <label class="produit_type">
    <input type="checkbox" name="produit_type[]" value="家居">家居
  </label>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: That's why I need to ask again, cause all the similar answers I found here, they just give a part of it, it makes me forget the most important thing, the click function! So your help is very useful for me!

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, I know this is an old thread but how would you do it if you have 2 different sets of check boxes and you need to remove the required only if a checkbox is selected for each set.

```
<form>
  <label class="produit_type">
    <input type="checkbox" name="produit_type[]" value="blah"
  </label>
  <label class="produit_type">
    <input type="checkbox" name="produit_type[]" value="blah blah"
  </label>
  <label class="produit_type">
    <input type="checkbox" name="produit_color[]" value="red"
  </label>
  <label class="produit_type">
    <input type="checkbox" name="produit_color[]" value="green"
  </label>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Just keeping the form simple.  So 2 sets of checkboxes one set for type and one set for color.  The code supplied would make either all of them required or all of them not required.  How would one adapt this code so that way it only affects each set as it's own?

For example if they select type but not color, it would remove required on type but keep required on color and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

```
var checkbox_required = $('input[type="checkbox"]');

checkbox_required.attr('required', true);

checkbox_required.on('click', function(){
    if (checkbox_required.is(':checked')) {
        checkbox_required.attr('required', false);
    } else {
        checkbox_required.attr('required', true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple groups with different names then this solution work perfect
Note: Add the uncheck validations

```
  $(document).on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]',function (e) {
      var inputname = $(this).attr('name');
      $("input[name='"+inputname+"']").prop('required', false);  
  });
```